# Query gives an unsorted result set when run from stored procedure using CTE

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression, row-number

I am trying to create a paging query using CTE. It works fine when I execute it from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Query Editor. And the result set is perfectly sorted as I want. But when I modify it for a stored procedure it gives me a unsorted result and I don't have any clue why.

Here is my Query,

```
with items as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by create_time desc) number
    , i.item_name item_name
    , i.create_time create_time
    , c.category_name category_name
    , i.category_id category_id
from cb_item i, cb_category c
where i.category_id = c.category_id
and c.category_id = '4E5248FE-05DD-4D01-ABBB-80C6E3BA5CDA' 
)
select item_name
, create_time
, category_name
, category_id
from items
where number between 1 and 25
```

And this is the Stored Procedure Version,

```
    create procedure ItemPage @category_id uniqueidentifier
    , @from int
    , @to int
    , @sortby nvarchar(50)
    as
    begin
    with items as
    (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by @sortby) number
        , i.item_name item_name
        , i.create_time create_time
        , c.category_name category_name
        , i.category_id category_id
    from cb_item i, cb_category c
    where i.category_id = c.category_id
    and c.category_id = @category_id 
    )
    select item_name
    , create_time
    , category_name
    , category_id
    from items
    where number between @from and @to
    end


exec itempage '4E5248FE-05DD-4D01-ABBB-80C6E3BA5CDA' , 1, 25, 'create_time desc'
```

The first one gives me sorted result but procedure gives me unsorted result. I don't know why?

Comment: what's create_time type in first query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Case in order by statement where you can check passed value and accordingly can order by row.

Your query should be like this:

```
 create procedure ItemPage @category_id uniqueidentifier
        , @from int
        , @to int
        , @sortby nvarchar(50)
        as
        begin
        with items as
        (
        select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by
                                    CASE @sortby
                                    WHEN 'create_time desc' THEN  create_time -- Here, I assume passed @sortby value is create_time , otherwise you can mapped with passed value
                                    END
                                    DESC,
                                    CASE @sortby
                                    WHEN 'create_time asc' THEN  create_time -- Here, I assume passed @sortby value is create_time , otherwise you can mapped with passed value
                                    END
                                    ASC
                                    ) number
            , i.item_name item_name
            , i.create_time create_time
            , c.category_name category_name
            , i.category_id category_id
        from cb_item i, cb_category c
        where i.category_id = c.category_id
        and c.category_id = @category_id 
        )
        select item_name
        , create_time
        , category_name
        , category_id
        from items
        where number between @from and @to
        end
```

Comment: Hi @LolCoder,

Thank you very much to show me some light. i am actually sending the sorting column with order type in the **@sortby** parameter. like, **'create_time desc' or 'create_time asc'**. 
But i can't convert my parameter to case statement here, like when i compare it 
`CASE @sortby 
    when 'create_time desc' then create_time DESC 
    when 'create_time asc' then create_time ASC
END`

It throw me a error before DESC or ASC